# Android Studio GUI components missing in palette

Tags: android, user-interface, components, textfield, palette

I couldn't find most of the GUI components in the palette, like Textfields... I haven't installed all of the sdk tools but I would appreciate if someone would tell me the required sdk tools that I need to download from sdk manager in order to be able to design GUI with all the components out there!

thanks in advance

Comment: Android does not have anything named "Textfields". If you are referring to `EditText`, they are in the "Text" category of the palette. There are no additional "required sdk tools" to use `EditText` in Android Studio.

Comment: "text fields widget is missing" -- there is nothing with that name in the Android SDK. You might consider uploading a screenshot somewhere and linking to it from your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply go to sdk manager of your Android studio  and check any android platform you want to install. This will install the required tools for building apps.
That's all.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Have you considered elaborating on the steps in your answer?